# Filesystem errors when installing Windows service from command-line

Tags: mysql

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqld -- install
2019-07-30T15:08:27.660210Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.17) starting as process 1720
2019-07-30T15:08:27.670665Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2019-07-30T15:08:27.670899Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2019-07-30T15:08:27.671342Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
2019-07-30T15:08:27.695923Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-07-30T15:08:27.696325Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.17)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

[image: Screenshot of my command prompt]

Comment: As far as I know you cannot install Windows services from a non-elevated command prompt. You need to run it as administrator. Whatever, you already installed MySQL Server with (I presume) the user-friendly wizard; I'm not sure why you're running command-line stuff.

Comment: Plus you have an straneous space between `--` and `install` :-?

Comment: (Install/Remove of the Service Denied!) now i got this error

Comment: i install successfully mysqld... but still ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Comment: kindly someone help me with this plz

Comment: I honestly can't understand what you need help with exactly or what your ultimate goal is. If you just want to install the software, let the wizard do the job—running random commands can only corrupt the installation, if it haven't already.